# Python class calling function that belongs to same class

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to call function that belongs to same function. Below is the code

```
class Asrconfig():
    def __init__(self, hostname, net_username, net_password):

        ''' SSH connection Establish '''
        self.hostname = hostname
        self.net_username = net_username
        self.net_password = net_password
    def connect(self, cmd):
        print "connect"
        self.cmd = cmd
        self.remote_conn_pre = paramiko.SSHClient()
        self.remote_conn_pre.set_missing_host_key_policy(
            paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
        self.remote_conn_pre.connect(self.hostname, username=self.net_username,
            password=self.net_password,look_for_keys=False, allow_agent=False)
        self.remote_conn = self.remote_conn_pre.invoke_shell()
        buff = ''
        remote_conn.send(cmd)
        while not buff.endswith('#'):
            resp = remote_conn.recv(9999)
            buff += resp
            print resp
    def inventory(self, cmd):
        cmd = "show inventory"
        self.connect(cmd)
asr = Asrconfig(hostname, net_username, net_password)
asr.inventory()
```

I am getting below output when I run the output:

```
RP#
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "onboard/testpara1.py", line 43, in <module>
    asr.inventory()
TypeError: inventory() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

I need below help

I am not able to call connect function in class Asrconfig under inventory function.

Comment: `inventory` takes a `cmd` argument, but you just called `asr.inventory()` without passing anything.

Comment: Also, why is `inventory()` even accepting an argument? All you do is overwrite the value in the function.

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite your `inventory` method like this:

```
def inventory(self, cmd="show inventory"):
    self.connect(cmd)
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution to your question:

```
class Asrconfig:
def __init__(self, hostname, net_username, net_password):
    ''' SSH connection Establish '''
    self.hostname = hostname
    self.net_username = net_username
    self.net_password = net_password
def connect(self, cmd):
    print "connect"
    self.cmd = cmd
    self.remote_conn_pre = paramiko.SSHClient()
    self.remote_conn_pre.set_missing_host_key_policy(
        paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    self.remote_conn_pre.connect(self.hostname, username=self.net_username,
        password=self.net_password,look_for_keys=False, allow_agent=False)
    self.remote_conn = self.remote_conn_pre.invoke_shell()
    buff = ''
    remote_conn.send(cmd)
    while not buff.endswith('#'):
        resp = remote_conn.recv(9999)
        buff += resp
        print resp
def inventory(self, cmd):
    cmd = "show inventory"
    self.connect(cmd)  

asr = Asrconfig(hostname, net_username, net_password)
# You need to pass parameter in inventory() method.
asr.inventory("Hello kitty...")
```